# nchar vs. nvarchar as primary keys in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I normally work with surrogate, numeric primary keys. But now I must use a textual primary key of 10 characters.

My question is whether it should be nchar or nvarchar? Thanks.

**Edit**

I appreciate your replies -I am aware of the differences between nchar and nvarchar, my question really is which one should I use for a primary key, thank you.

Comment: Does your 10-character identifier really have the potential to contain Unicode text? If not, you're wasting two bytes for every character, and should use `char` instead of `nchar`.

Answer (score 2):

The advice from [T-SQL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) is pretty straightforward:

> Use nchar when the sizes of the column data entries are probably going
>   to be similar. Use nvarchar when the sizes of the column data entries
>   are probably going to vary considerably.

In your case, a 10 char identifier, the answer is nchar.